# Downloading file using wget in Termux fails due to the character '&' in the URL

Tags: downloading, termux, url

When I simply put this URL in my Android Chrome or any web browser:

```
https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AHT.L,AZN.L,AUTO.L,AVV.L,AV.L&api_token=39W3kqXKo1zm04k5De0yutk7iNtEKygnYPqDTowXy94EwgBUNAb3yY3XHHbN&output=csv
```

I get the file: `worldtradingdata-realtimeprices.csv`

But when I put this in Termux:

```
wget -O /storage/emulated/0/Download/worldtradingdata-realtimeprices.csv https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AHT.L,AZN.L,AUTO.L,AVV.L,AV.L&api_token=39W3kqXKo1zm04k5De0yutk7iNtEKygnYPqDTowXy94EwgBUNAb3yY3XHHbN&output=csv/worldtradingdata-realtimeprices.csv
```

I get this instead

```
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.2’.
```

When I press enter, I get

```
[1]- Done wget -O /storage/emulated/0/Download/worldtradingdata-realtimeprices.csv https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AHT.L,AZN.L,AUTO.L,AVV.L,AV.L [2]+ Done api_token=39W3kqXKo1zm04k5De0yutk7iNtEKygnYPqDTowXy94EwgBUNAb3yY3XHHbN $
```

It breaks where "&" comes in my URL after `AV.L` and before `api_token`,

How to download a file having '&' in the URL with `wget` in Termux?

Answer (score 2):

Put all the URL argument into a single quotes. You'll get something like this:

```
wget -O /storage/emulated/0/Download/worldtradingdata-realtimeprices.csv 'https://api.worldtradingdata.com/api/v1/stock?symbol=AHT.L,AZN.L,AUTO.L,AVV.L,AV.L&api_token=39W3kqXKo1zm04k5De0yutk7iNtEKygnYPqDTowXy94EwgBUNAb3yY3XHHbN&output=csv/worldtradingdata-realtimeprices.csv'
```

Single quotes will disable special meaning of meta-characters like &

In addition, I'd suggest you to regenerate the api token.